# JQ data-target (a) link toggle this; prevent e

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi I have JQuery Toggle div thing working, Ive set it up to be a navigation panel and need to stop users from clicking on the same link again, as this hides div leaving page blank. I guess im trying to hook into the selected data-target (a) link and disable click action or prevent arguement, only on this the selected target. Cheers P

This is my code:

```
$('.home').css({
    display: 'visible'
});

$('.contact').css({
    display: 'none'
});

var $targets = $('.target');

$('.navBtn').click(function () {
  var $target = $($(this).data('target')).fadeToggle('slow');
  $targets.not($target).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

And the html:

```
<a class="navBtn" data-target=".home">
  <img src="img/icons/home.svg" width="100%" />
</a>
<a class="navBtn" data-target=".contact">
  <img src="assets/img/icons/message.svg" width="100%" />
</a>
```

Comment: So why not just use `fadein()` instead? http://jsfiddle.net/c1sb1d3c/

Comment: @Shaunak was I over complicating that one! Thanx

Comment: Glad to help, I'll post it as answer so this question wouldnt be left unanswered; you can accept it if useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need the element to appear and not toggle, use `.fadeIn()`

```
$('.navBtn').click(function () {
  var $target = $($(this).data('target')).fadeIn('slow');
  $targets.not($target).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c1sb1d3c/)**